# Custom marker wrong position when zooming

Tags: android, maps

I'm implementing a map in my android app, with a custom marker.

The problem is that since my custom marker is a circle, and not a pointing arrow (like the default one), when the map is very zoomed, the position marked is more or less right. But when i zoom out a lot, the marker is in the wrong position, since the library put the lower border of the icon on the coordinates giver, and not the center of it.

How can i fix this?

Comment: How about add offset for the latitude